# How many powered external USB 3.0 hard disk (not SSD) drives can I reliably run off an unpowered USB 3.0 hub?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

The HDDs have their own power sources but the USB hub - 7 ports - is unpowered. Could I use all 7 ports and get reliable data transfer?

Comment: Yes you can use all 7, how reliable it is only you can know by trying.

Comment: Reliability of USB 3.0 connection(s) depends on quality of hub internal design - its power supplies, power distribution to ports, signal integrity (cross-talk between ports), etc. Depending on manufacturer and luck, it can be anything. This question therefore makes no sense. Use USB-IF certified hubs (if you can find one), and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Power_and_charging):

> As with earlier versions of USB, USB 3.0 provides power at 5 volts
>   nominal. The available current for low-power (one unit load)
>   SuperSpeed devices is 150 mA, an increase from the 100 mA defined in
>   USB 2.0. For high-power SuperSpeed devices, the limit is six unit
>   loads or 900 mA (4.5 W), almost twice USB 2.0's 500 mA.[10]:section
>   9.2.5.1 Power Budgeting
>
> The term "available current" can be misunderstood. It implies that if
>   a low power device or a USB2 device is connected to a USB3 port it can
>   only draw 150 mA or 500 mA from that port. However, the available
>   current for any USB device plugged into a USB3 port is 900 mA (unless
>   it is charging port compliant) as defined by the USB3 spec. The actual
>   current draw is determined by the device capability. The Vbus, pin 1,
>   and Ground, pin 4, are the same for USB 1, 2, or 3. A USB2 HDD with 2
>   USB2 connectors needing a total of 800 mA will draw full power from a
>   single USB3 port. A USB2 phone will probably charge faster since 900
>   mA is "available" to it.
>
> USB 3.0 ports may implement other USB specifications for increased
>   power, including the USB Battery Charging Specification for up to 1.5
>   A or 7.5 W, or, in the case of USB 3.1, the USB Power Delivery
>   Specification for charging the host device up to 100 W.[12]

If you plug your unpowered USB hub into a standard USB 3 port, it can draw a maximum of 900mA from that port. (That is, if your USB 3 port meets the specs; I can imagine some motherboard manufacturers taking some shortcuts to save costs.)

That means, you can connect 7 SSDs, as long as their total current draw is less than 900mA (or 128mA each). I assume here that the HUB takes (almost) no power.

The best way to find out is to look at the current draw specs of your SSDs and, as mentioned in one of the comments, you can find out by trying how reliable your set-up is.

You can run some SSD read/write speeds to find out. First start with one SSD, run the tests and then plug the 2nd one in and run the tests again, until you have all 7 plugged in or your tests start failing.

Comment: Good research but your conclusion at the end is not quite there.  The power is all in increments of unit loads.  Any unpowered device gets at least 1 unit load (allocated one and then negotiates for more if needed).  The hub, itself, takes 1.  So an unpowered hub could connect a maximum of 5 unpowered devices.  The question describes the drives as self-powered.  If they are self-powered at the time they are plugged in, the hub may not try to allocate power to them, in which case, 7 could potentially work.  (cont'd)

Comment: USB 3.0 has enough bandwidth that there probably wouldn't be much performance degradation for 7 hard drives (SSD performance would suffer).

Comment: They are not SSDs if that makes a difference. They are all HDDs.

Comment: @Moonling, it could work if the drives are powered at the time they're connected.  You pretty much need to try it to verify.